# Check if PouchDB database is empty

Tags: javascript, html, pouchdb

I am working on an app which stores data locally using PouchDB. It displays a list of items and I would like to be able to check if the database is empty so that in the case that it is, I can append a line 'Your list is empty' to the DOM. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several ways to do this. You could query and check for an empty result list. You can also use `db.info()`.

```
db.info().then(function (result) {
  if(result.doc_count === 0) {
    console.log('It's empty!');
  }
});
```